# Why is Excel Document Printing at Bottom of Page when Orientation is Landscape?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, printer, spreadsheet

We just replaced our office printer from a Canon ImageClass MF3240 to a much newer Canon ImageClass MF260. When we try to print Excel spreadsheets in landscape orientation the printer will print the pages with the document aligned at the bottom of the page, this does not happen on our old printer. [Example: Top (Old Printer), Bottom (New)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7wji.jpg)

I have combed through both our printer settings and preferences and our excel printing preferences to no avail. Printing on Portrait works fine. I have changed the double sided settings, margins, flip on fold settings, but the results remain the same.

Comment: You must be putting the paper into the tray the other way around.  :-)  If everything else prints correctly, it pretty much has to be a setting in Excel.  We would need all of that detail in order to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Did you check if the print driver correct?

Comment: Create a Landscape doc in Word and see how that prints.

Comment: Try some other Print with Word and others if in general the problem persists the Check the Switch Setting or re install the printer ☺

Comment: The printer is a wireless network printer, I didn't do an installation on any of our network computers, I just connect and print. I have scoured excel settings without any luck. Documents print fine from other printers and from programs like Word.

Comment: My excel spreadsheet prints correctly to other printers, but not to the new one, even from other versions of excel and other network computers.

Comment: Correction Word prints incorrectly in landscape if and only if page is not a full page.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers automatically installed by windows were incorrect. I went to Canon's site and downloaded the correct drivers and reinstalled, this solved the problem.